# Detect onMouseOut only of parent element

Tags: javascript

I have an `<img>` wraped with a `<div>`, on hover based on a state I need to display an element (`<TagsDropdown />`) on the image and to hide it when `isHoveing=false`.

```
  <div>
          <img
             className={classes.img}
             src={photo.src}
             onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
             onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
          />
          <div className={classes.tagContainer}>
             <Tag
                 tag={tag}
                 key={tag}
             />
             {isHovering && (
                <TagsDropdown />
             )}
          </div>
    </div>
```

I'm able to display the element properly but I can't figure out how to hide it,
when the user hover the elemnt iside the image it's being detected as `onMouseOut` because it's a different element than the image.

```
  const onMouseOver = e => {
    setIsHovering(true)
  }

  const onMouseOut = e => {
    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.tagName == 'IMG') {
      setIsHovering(false)
      return
    }
  }
```

I tried with `e.relatedTarget.tagName` and `e.target.tagName` but the first one is always a `div` and the second one returns an `img`.

Comment: Listen `mouseleave` event on the parent, it won't fire when a child element is left.

Comment: Replace your test **if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.tagName == 'IMG')** with something like:
**if (e.relatedTarget.tagName == 'DIV') and IMG's isHovering is true**

Comment: @Teemu, thank you, works perfectly, would you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be done with staight CSS and a :hover selector? I am using a :hover on the wraping div - and display : none / block on the :hover.

You might need to leave the display alone and do it iwith position or other styling - ubt you shouldn't need JS to determine the hover state and associated visibility / position of the element.

```
//css
TagsDropdown {
  display: none;
}

.img-wrapper:hover TagsDropdown {
  display: block;
}


// html
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img
       className={classes.img}
       src={photo.src}
    />
    <div className={classes.tagContainer}>
       <Tag
           tag={tag}
           key={tag}
       />
      <TagsDropdown/>
    </div>
</div>
```